# Why do you apply tanh twice to the hidden state to compute the output?

Tags: lstm

I've already seen different lectures on LSTMs and each time, I realize that there is one point that I've never really understood, so I hope that someone here can explain or give a hint as to why it is doen that way.

According to the formulas on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), the simplest LSTM consists of the following formulas:
\begin{aligned}f_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{f}x_{t}+U_{f}h_{t-1}+b_{f})\\i_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{i}x_{t}+U_{i}h_{t-1}+b_{i})\\o_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{o}x_{t}+U_{o}h_{t-1}+b_{o})\\{\tilde {c}}_{t}&=\sigma _{c}(W_{c}x_{t}+U_{c}h_{t-1}+b_{c})\\c_{t}&=f_{t}\circ c_{t-1}+i_{t}\circ {\tilde {c}}_{t}\\h_{t}&=o_{t}\circ \sigma _{h}(c_{t})\end{aligned}

My question now is: Why do you need another non-linearity sigma_h to compute the new hidden state. Since ct is already a superposition of two sigmoids, wouldn't it be sufficient to just multiply the output gate with c_t and - if necessary - rescale it so that the result is in [0,1]?

I would be a happy man, if someone could elaborate on this... :-)

Comment: OK, so just now when I wrote down my question, I get a feeling why this is necessary: Probably otherwise the cell state and the hidden state are too similar, right?

Comment: I am not aware of the original publication but certainly one wants one extra degree of freedom there to make the model more versatile and adaptable. Else it becomes more limited.